# Как смотреть исходники java из idea?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Как настроить intelij idea, чтобы можно было перейти к читабельным исходникам, например посмотреть, как реализован HashSet

Comment: Ctrl + клик на нужный класс

Answer (score 3):

Для начала, открыть настройки проекта и убедиться, что в разделе `SDKs` для Java на вкладке `Sourcepath` указаны пути до архивов с исходниками JDK.

[image]

Если это так, то перейти к реализации того или иного класса или метода можно щелчком левой кнопкой мыши с нажатой клавишой `Ctrl`. Также можно воспользоваться пунктами `Go To` из контекстного меню.

Comment: Откуда можно скачать архив с исходниками?

Comment: @VladislavOsipenkov обычно они поставляются в комплекте с JDK